# Running python package from node.js

Tags: python, node.js

I have a python application that I want to run in node.js. All of the examples that I saw were on how to run a single file, however, I have multiple files that have dependencies.

Basically I want to run main python file which will execute other python files.

I've tried python-shell npm package, and it seems to be running, however, it just runs the python file and doesn't do anything. The python scripts takes in a csv file, reads it, transforms it and exports it to the database. However, my db is not altered after running python script from node.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')

    let options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonPath: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3',
        pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
        scriptPath: './folder1/dm-portal'
      };


    PythonShell.run('python-file.py', options, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('finished');
    });
```

I run my python script using node python.py and it gives me finished basically immediately which makes no sense as the whole python process takes like 20 mins to run.

Any ideas how I could run a folder full of python files using one main file?

Answer (score 0):

where is the output result, console log that. there should be an error

```
PythonShell.run('python-file.py', options, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  if(result){
     console.log('result : ', result)
   }
});
```